# Avoid p4 stream -t release -P //depot/main //depot/release0.1 popup

Tags: git, svn, perforce, perforce-client-spec

When I type the following p4 command in the cmd:

p4 stream -t release -P //depot/main //depot/release0.1

It will give an popup for detailed configuration, I am wondering if there is a way to avoid the popup window and set the desired options by using cmd?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can update the stream spec without invoking your interactive editor by using 'stream -i' and providing the stream data on stdin.

For example, prepare a file with the information that you would have typed in your editor, call it 'streamdata.txt', and enter:

```
p4 stream -i < streamdata.txt
```